# How to get an XElement, and create it if it doesn't exist?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

Is there a way to use something like [Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element.aspx) method in XContainer, but will create a new XElement and return that if the Element with the specified name doesn't exist in the container?

Comment: I suspect this method exists in dozens if not hundreds of utility classes around the world... just not in one published by Microsoft

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should write it yourself. It should be a static helper method.

```
    private static XElement GetOrCreateElement(XContainer container, string name) {
        var element = container.Element(name);
        if(element == null)
        {
           element = new XElement(name);
            container.Add(element);
        }
        return element;
    }
```

If you wish to use member call syntax, make it an extension method by adding "this" in front of XContainer. In this case, the method shall be in a static class with no field that you may call "XContainerExtensions".

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to write that functionality yourself:

```
var element = container.Element("name");
if(element == null)
{
    element = new XElement("name");
    container.Add(element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not possible since Linq-to-XML is a query language for XML-Data and does not provide CRUD operations while querying. You have to use two steps.

First query for your element, and if i doesn´t exist you have to add your new element to your container.